# Publishing from Visual studio fails

Tags: web, publish

[image]

Visual studio started giving me this error on publish
My deploy is based on web deploy and its happens for other project in the same solution
I've created a new deploy profile yet, disabled firewall, checked server permissions, , but the problem persists

alert message:
Web Deploy experienced a connection problem with the server and had to terminate the connection.  Contact your server administrator if the problem persists.  Learn more at: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_CONNECTION_TERMINATED. Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are not closed: results. Line 1, position 550.

Comment: Please [edit] to paste the text used in the image into your question so that it can be read on all devices, quoted, edited, and found through search. As it stands now, [your image makes it hard to answer your question or for people with related issues to find your question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). See the [formatting documentation](/editing-help) for tips to make your text appear nicely without resorting to images.